# google app engine with django retrieve item by key from a template to a view

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

i have this small problem with google app engine i want to retrieve images from datastore , my function is 100 percent working if i enter the key inside the code on the other hand if i get as a parameter it would give me BadKeyError

here is the form

```
        {% for image in image.all %}
            <li>{{ image.title }}  </li>
            <img src='getImage?key={{image.key}}' height="100" />
```

maped to

```
def getImage(request,key):
image = Image()
request.encoding = 'koi8-r'
image = db.get(key) 
#build your response
response = HttpResponse(image.blob)
# set the content type to png because that's what the Google images api 
# stores modified images as by default
response['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
# set some reasonable cache headers unless you want the image pulled on every    request
response['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=7200'
return response
```

Comment: How is the `key` parameter getting to the view? You're sending it as a GET variable, but seem to be expecting it as a normal URL parameter. What does your urls.py look like?

Comment: When you say "mapped to" what do you mean. In your example it looks very much like you have just written the function name `getImage` name in the `src` attribute rather than a url that points to your handler?

Answer (score 0):

I created something simliar to what you want to achieve.. Hope this helps

**image.py**

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
class Profile(db.Model):
                image=db.BlobProperty()
class disp_image(webapp.RequestHandler):       
                def get(self): 
                    key = self.request.get('key')
                    image = Profile.get(key)
                    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
                    return self.response.out.write(image.image)
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        image = self.request.get('image')
        pro=Profile()
        if image:   
            pro.image = db.Blob(image)
            import logging
            logging.info('persisted')
            pro.put()
        prof=Profile().all()

        return self.response.out.write(template.render('view.html',{'prof':prof}))
    def post(self):
        return MainPage.get(self)
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/disp', disp_image)
], debug=True)
def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/">
<input type="file" name='image'/>
<input type='submit' value="submit"/>
{% for prof in prof %}
<img src="/disp?key={{prof.key}}" />
{% endfor %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: sample-app
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: image.py
```

url

```
>>> req.host
'localhost:80'
>>> req.host_url
'http://localhost'
>>> req.application_url
'http://localhost/blog'
>>> req.path_url
'http://localhost/blog/article'
>>> req.url
'http://localhost/blog/article?id=1'
>>> req.path
'/blog/article'
>>> req.path_qs
'/blog/article?id=1'
>>> req.query_string
'id=1'
```

Comment: do you know how to retrieve a string in the url patterns , like the url pattern only take decimals values and they are fixed like     getImage/(\d{1})/ is there anyway else to retrieve a paramter to the view

Comment: Like you said you can pass it in the url and get it . Use req.url and do some split and get the key